# Multidimensional Array structure to PHP HTML output?

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array, output

I have repeated sections in my web site.

I'm trying to decrease them,

My approach is one time i will create a html schema (predefined as array), via this schema my function undestranding that what kind of output user needs and outputs results according to my variables..

My problem is I could not find a way to complete situation..

Input variables might be (infinitive)

```
$vals = array('Country Name' => 'USA', 'Country Name' => 'Canada', 'Country Name' => 'Mexico');

$vals = array('Country Name' => 'USA', 'Country Name' => 'Canada');

$vals = array('Country Name' => 'USA');
```

Expected outputs are in order

```
<div class="lines">
    <div><span>Country Name</span>USA</div>
    <div><span>Country Name</span>Canada</div>
    <div><span>Country Name</span>Mexico</div>
</div>

<div class="lines">
    <div><span>Country Name</span>USA</div>
    <div><span>Country Name</span>Canada</div>
</div>

<div class="lines">
    <div><span>Country Name</span>USA</div>
</div>
```

Schema is the variables that is totally suitable with html

```
$schema = array(
    array(
        'tag' => 'div',
        'class' => 'lines',
        array(
            'tag' => 'div',
             array(
                'tag' => 'span',
                'key' => '$key'
            ),
            'key' => '$key'
        ),
    )
);
```

My function creates outputs from this schema. (Schema might be expand accordings to user need.)

```
function get_output($schema, $vals, $t = -1){
    $t++;

    $tag = "";
    $atts = array();
    $keys = array();
    $code = array();

    foreach($schema as $k => $v){        
        if(is_array($v)){
            $keys[] = get_output($v, $vals, $t);
        } else {
            switch($k){
                case "tag": $tag = $v; break;
                case "key": break;
                case "type":   break;
                default: $atts[$k] = $v; break;
            }
        }    
    }

    if($tag){
        $code[] = "<$tag"; 
        foreach($atts as $k=>$v)
        { 
            $code[] = ' '.$k.'="'.urlencode($v).'"'; 
        }
        $code[] = ">";
        $code = array(implode('', $code));
    }
    foreach($keys as $k)
    { 
      $code[] = $k;
    } 

    if($tag){
        $code[] = '</'.$tag.'>'; 
    }
    return implode("", $code);
}
```

After all this process I will just call my function with the variables., Schema predefined once.

```
$vals = array('Country Name' => 'USA', 'Country Name' => 'Canada', 'Country Name' => 'Mexico');

echo get_output($schema, $vals, -1);
```

UPDATE1

My current output is the following html code, I could not find a way to push variables. Which are Country Name / Country

```
<div class="lines">
    <div><span></span></div>
    <div><span></span></div>
</div>
```

UPDATE3 Different Approach to Schema

```
$schema = array(
    'div' => array(
        'class' => 'lines',
        'div' => array(
             'span' => array(
                'key' => '$k[0]'
            ),
            'key' => '$k[1]'
        )
);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Patrick Kostjens I want to have outputs from this function which are defined @ question.

Comment: What are you getting now then? And what where you expecting?

Comment: I get <div class="lines">
    <div><span></span></div>
    <div><span></span></div>
</div> only NO Variables

Comment: I could not find a way to push my variables inside output function.

Comment: I don't think your current schema is sufficient. It doesn't state where the values should be entered in the output. I'll continue on your code when you've updated your schema so that that is also clear.

Comment: Do you have suggession? About schema?

Comment: My guess would be that the last `'key' => $key` should be `'value' => $value`

Comment: Container array will be master (constant) and inner array will must be repetative. Html tags have only one keys. Does Replace the first key can be an approach?

Comment: But if you look at html output this is also key for container div..

Comment: I created better schema at UPDATE2 but I dont think that this is possible to use.

Comment: Is it an option to completely revise your code? I think a object oriented approach where each object renders itself and knows its keys and values would be much better and easier to understand.

Comment: About update2, why is there a constant value in there? Isn't something like soap something that should come from your values so that it can vary?

Comment: Yes completely revise is possible.

Comment: Then I advise you to do that. If you run into problems then, you can ask another question.

Comment: You are definetely right that Understanding this function is so hard.

Comment: Can you explain this approach? " I think a object oriented approach where each object renders itself and knows its keys and values would be much better and easier to understand" or give an example?

Comment: About update2 contant value just an example. This is variable.

Comment: Check out update3, may be this might be solution.

Comment: I can't give an example in a comment. Read about OOP. You probably want an object that can render itself and that object can then have children of the same class. You can then pass the values that should be used by the object in the constructor. This is not a detailed explanation of what you should do, but I think you should just try it and come back with another questions if you run into problems. I don't think you should be using a solution using a scheme like this with code like this at all. It's not scalable and hard to understand.

Comment: @Partich Kostjens I know about OOP, But how could be possible to render itselt. Because if you check my function variable amounts are not constant.

Comment: I'm looking for an alternative approach

Comment: Just create a method that returns the html for that object. You can then call that method from your 'main' script. You can create object instances in a foreach loop so that's no problem.

Comment: You mean, https://code.google.com/p/phpcreatehtml/? My point is creating suitable html elements from array. Not with tags.

Comment: You can use that, but you don't have to.

Comment: @PatrickKostjens I have 2000 lines of html codes for every page. %75 are repetative. I do not want to use forech loop outside of function. I want to get all output from a function. I will just give variable names and keys, and function will return me suitable output according to schema..

Comment: @PatrickKostjens thank you for your help I found another approach. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418228/is-it-possible-to-send-array-key-names-inside-function